# Not able to call a jQuery function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to get the file input preview working.

I have a `jquery` script which works fine when I call the function normally.

```
$('#images').on("change", previewImages);
```

[This](https://jsfiddle.net/jrqv72bk/#&togetherjs=y3g7khI8Kw) works.

But when I put the call to the same function differently like following

```
 $('#images').on("change", function(){

   previewImages();

 });
```

[This](https://jsfiddle.net/fut7n2fo/3/) doesn't work.

I need to write an `if else statement` to call a different function on else.

Comment: it is working when i checked

Comment: Yes its working!!!

Comment: Both fiddles include $('#images').on("change", previewImages);

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** - can you provide a *minimal* example where it's not working?  See [mcve].

Comment: @krishnar the first one is working but not the second one

Comment: @RahulMeshram the first one is working but not the second one

Comment: what should happen in second one.. preview image right? its happening

Comment: @KillerDeath the second one is calling it differently. I don't know how it got changed by itself

Comment: @chris, Someone must have changed it, I see there is an invitation for a collaboration or something when you open it.

Comment: differently means what? try to explain what exactly you want to achieve?

Comment: @KillerDeath, how can I stop that invitation? please

Comment: @chris, I don't know, never seen that on people's fiddles before

Comment: @chris, try clicking collaborate in menu above

Comment: @KillerDeath, I have disabled the collaboration. thanks for pointing out

Comment: @chris No problem, but in the meanwhile  someone changed the second one again.

Comment: @KillerDeath, I have put it back to the original one. Thats how I am intended to get it working

Comment: Sorry its valid question

Comment: @all it's valid question..please upvote his question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Valid question**

Reason: this happens because of `this` which refers to file element when you are using first approach but in case of second approach `this` is referring to window element in which it is called. So pass this to function and your question is solved.

```
$('#images').on("change", function(e) {
    /* issue is with this */
    previewImages(e, this);
});

var count = 0;

function previewImages(evt, cur) {
    var $fileUpload = $("input#images[type='file']");
    count = count + parseInt($fileUpload.get(0).files.length);
    if (parseInt($fileUpload.get(0).files.length) > 7 || count > 6) {
        alert("You can only upload a maximum of 6 files");
        count = count - parseInt($fileUpload.get(0).files.length);
        evt.preventDefault();
        evt.stopPropagation();
        return false;
    }
    $("#taskbar").css("height", "auto");
    var $preview = $('#preview').empty();
    if (cur.files) $.each(cur.files, readAndPreview);
    function readAndPreview(i, file) {
        // if (!/\.(jpe?g|png|gif|mp4)$/i.test(file.name)){
        //   return alert(file.name +" is not an image");
        // }
        var reader = new FileReader();
        $('#preview img').addClass('img-responsive');
        $(reader).on("load", function() {
            $preview.append($("<img/>", {
                src: this.result,
                height: 100
            }));
        });
        reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why does it refer to file element in first approach and not window?

Comment: @KillerDeath because its on change event and u get file element directly and in second case within function calling one more function so event target is changed which is window.

Comment: always problems with "this" in javascript, thought since the beginning it was something about that, just doing some reading on it. Answer's useful, upvoting.

Comment: @chris         Please upvote my answer if its useful :)

Answer (score 0):

Create a prePreviewImages function, and use that in your first approach. Inside that function, use the if-statement and call previewImages() or your other function.

Answer (score 0):

The following should do..

```
 $('#images').change(function(e) {    
         if(e == "some condition"){  // if else goes here
              previewImages(); 
         }else {
            SomeOtherFun();
         }
     });
```

Comment: Given that the `e` parameter is always provided to the event handler, I'm not sure exactly what you're expecting this to do

Answer (score 0):

Both ways seem to work for me on the JSFiddle. Are you sure it is not a 
[browser compatibility issue](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader#Browser_compatibility)?

If not are you getting errors logged in the console under developer tools?

Comment: the second one doesn't work. I am not sure how someone else updated it, but I have put it back how I want it to work. Thanks